# Dynamically replace image src after the page loaded and the image is completely downloaded

Tags: jquery, image, lazy-loading

Am trying to create a simple lazy image load to replace default image with main item image after page has loaded and image is fully downloaded. But am getting and error using below jquery code.

**HTML Example**

```
<img src="default.png" data-src="image-1.png" class="productImage"/>
<img src="default.png" data-src="image-2.png" class="productImage"/>
<img src="default.png" data-src="image-3.png" class="productImage"/>
<img src="default.png" data-src="image-4.png" class="productImage"/>
```

**Jquery Example**

```
$(function(){
    $('img.productImage').each(function(){
       var this_image = this;
       var src = $(this_image).attr('src');
       var lsrc = $(this_image).attr('data-src');
        if(lsrc.length > 0){
            var img = new Image();
            img.src = lsrc;
            $(img).load(function() {
                this_image.src = this.src;
            });
        }else{
            this_image.src = src;
        }
    });
});
```

The above script give this error `TypeError: e.indexOf is not a function[Learn More] jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2:82466`.

I have also tried to use below code and it worked but am not very sure that it does wait for the image to download before replacing the src, because it always replace one page load.

```
$(function(){
    $('img.productImage').each(function(){
       var this_image = this;
       var src = $(this_image).attr('src');
       var lsrc = $(this_image).attr('data-src');
            if(lsrc.length > 0){
                this_image.src = lsrc;
            }else{
                this_image.src = src;
            }

    });
});
```

Comment: Aside from the error, you state that this is intended to be a lazy loading script, yet it doesn't actually lazy load anything.

Comment: Separately: Always set `src` **after** hooking the `load` event, not before.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder can you please post an answer of what you mean

Comment: @Peter - No, I can't, because it's not an answer to the question. Edit: But I have an answer now. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) is not a shortcut for `.on("load"`, it does something completely different (loads HTML from the server and put it in the element). Separately, always hook the `load` event **before** setting `src`, not after, to avoid race conditions.

```
var img = new Image();
$(img).on("load", function() {
    this_image.src = this.src;
});
img.src = lsrc;
```

Using `on` instead of `load` solves the weird `url.indexOf` (`e.indexOf` in the minified version) error:

```js
$(function(){
    $('img.productImage').each(function(){
       var this_image = this;
       var src = $(this_image).attr('src');
       var lsrc = $(this_image).attr('data-src');
       if(lsrc.length > 0){
            var img = new Image();
            $(img).on("load", function() {
                this_image.src = this.src;
            });
            img.src = lsrc;
        }else{
            this_image.src = src;
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100?text=p" data-src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100/08f/000?text=1" class="productImage"/>
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100?text=p" data-src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100/08f/000?text=2" class="productImage"/>
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100?text=p" data-src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100/08f/000?text=3" class="productImage"/>
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100?text=p" data-src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100/08f/000?text=4" class="productImage"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```